# How can I search a sentence in a file?

Tags: java, full-text-search, document

I am trying to do a Search program.
But I don't know how search a sentence in a file.

In C# we can use `Linq`, but in Java I don't Know.

Comment: I think you can make use of [public boolean contains(CharSequence s)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Comment: Use string pattern matcher or contains method.

Comment: `grep sentence file.txt`

Answer (score 4):

Java loves to be difficult in both line-based and token-based scanning.

Heres an example of line based scanning for a sentence:

```
public static boolean scanFile(String sentence) {
    Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(new File("FileName.txt"));
    while (lineScan.hasNextLine()) {
        if (lineScan.nextLine().contains(sentence)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

And heres an example of token based scanning for a word:

```
public static boolean scanFile(String word) {
    Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(new File("FileName.txt"));
    while (lineScan.hasNextLine()) {
        Scanner tokenScan = new Scanner(s.nextLine());
        while (tokenScan.hasNext()) {
            if (tokenScan.next().equals(word)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```